# ajax 4.0 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentException: Value must not be null for Controls and Behaviors

Tags: runtime-error, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm in the throws of trying to upgrade my AJAX from 3.5 to 4.  A new issue I'm encountering is an error if my control visibility is set to hidden.

ajax 4.0 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentException: Value must not be null for Controls and Behaviors.

Anyone know how to get around this problem?  Code base is C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have anything else referencing the control you've hidden, such as a CascadingDropDown or any other control that lists your control by name?

This error can be caused by the library trying to reference the original control but not finding it. Look specifically in the page source for references to "$create", and ensure that the last param passed in does indeed point to a control on your page.